# java process creating tmp/tmp* files that are in deleted state but increasing the disk utilization in linux VM

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a java spring boot application that implements multi-threading where one thread subscribes to ZMQ and four parallel threads performs some processing on received data according to some scheduled intervals. When the jar is run on linux VM and open files are checked using command

```
lsof -s -p<pid>
```

it shows a file of type "tmp/tmp* ... (deleted)" whose disk utilization increases exponentially and the process tree shows that this file belongs to the running java process. This issue is encountered only on linux VM environment, not on linux host.

Application code does not have any such scenario where file is deleted without closing. Below is the code snippet that uses file handling :

```
File file = null;
        PrintWriter printWriter = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        FileWriter fileTruncateObject = null;
try {
                    file = new File(filePath);
                    printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
                    for (T obj : list) {

                        String jsonString = writeJsonString(obj);
                        if ((jsonString.getBytes().length + file.length()) < 123) {
                            printWriter.write(jsonString);
                            printWriter.flush();

                        }

                        if ((jsonString.getBytes().length + file.length() >= 123) {
                            printWriter.close();
                            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                            br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                            String data = br.readLine();
                            // do something with data
                            br.close();
                            fileReader.close();
                            // file reading successfull, now truncating the file and opening new printwriter object!
                            fileTruncateObject = new FileWriter(file, true);
                            fileTruncateObject.close();
                            printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
                        }

                    }
                } finally {
                    if (printWriter != null) {
                        printWriter.close();
                    }
                    if (br != null) {
                        try {
                            br.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                        }
                    }
                    if (fileReader != null) {
                        try {
                            fileReader.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                        }
                    }
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        try {
                            if (file.delete()) {
                                //
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Also, the application uses `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` with max size of 10 MB and max history of 15 days with following properties:

```
logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg%n
logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg%n
logging.level.com.*=DEBUG
logging.path=logs
logging.file=${logging.path}//a.%d.log
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
logging.file.max-size=10MB
logging.file.max-history=15
```

I can not read the content of the file as it is in deleted stage. Also, it is directed towards "2u" file descriptor. May be there are some errors happening in the process that are getting written in `/tmp` file but how can I know what are the errors and what is the reason behind those errors ? Is there anything that can be done to avoid creating this `/tmp` file or is there any way to read the contents of this file ?

Comment: The behaviour is not related to the use of the ZeroMQ framework, which was also excluded from an attempt to formulate problem using an MCVE-representation.

Comment: Are you certain that the code snippet presented is responsible for the particular files you're looking at?

Comment: Are any of those catch-and-ignore exceptions being thrown? If you can't log something because you're in a logger then at least stick a System.out.println in there for debug purposes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, No I am not certain that this code snippet is responsible. But, as per my research as of now this issue happens when files got deleted but remain in open state. The concern here is that I can not see what is being written in the /tmp file as it is getting deleted as soon as the application start.

Comment: @AndyBrown, no kind of exception is thrown in any case.

Comment: `new FileWriter(file, true)` doesn't truncate anything. Remove the second parameter, or set it to`false`. But the subsequent `new PrintWriter(...)` makes it all irrelevant. Too much useless code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command used to run the java process in linux VM involved "nohup" and "tee" for stdout. The output in the questionable /tmp/ was dependent on the data being received by the process (which was quite huge) and due to this the logs started getting printed on the /tmp/ as well as the log directory configured in property files. Simply redirecting the stdout and stderr of java process solved the issue.

example of correct command :

> `nohup java jar <jar name> 2>&1 > dev/null &`